# What does float argument and -ve number do in printf function in php

Tags: php, numbers, printf

I am running these two `printf()` functions and little bit confused with the output generated by them.

1. `printf("%0.4f",3467);`

It outputs - `3467.0000`. In first parameter that is `0.4f` 4 is understood as it represents 4 zeros after decimal but I am not sure about the `0` as I changed it to 1,2,3 it remains same. So what does it do ?

1. `printf("%1.6u\n", -32);`

While running this, I am getting `4294967264` what exactly does this number refers too ?

Before asking I checked [printf()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.printf.php) link whick is referring to [sprintf()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.sprintf.php) for parameter look up, but unable to find something on this.

Comment: `%u` is used to print an *unsigned* integer, you passed in a *signed* one. Garbage in = garbage out. `%0.4f` means "a floating point number, four decimal places, result string must be at least 0 characters long and left padded with spaces if necessary". If you change it to `%9.4f` or `%09.4f`, you'll see alternative results. Look at "width specifier" and other items described on that `sprintf` page above the format specifiers.

Comment: @DCoder I dont think its a garbage value as i tested it on code pad as well and it returning the same ouptup http://codepad.org/NAD2QSHe

Comment: @DCoder I executed this code but no effect  ..firebugged as well to check if some extra space added but NO its not printf("%13.4f",3467);

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The 0 in %0.4f is the minimum length the output will have when the value is formatted. In your case you will not see any difference in output unless you change it to 10 or above as the output like that will always be 3467.0000. If you change the 0 to 15 you will get one blank in front of the formatted output:

```
printf("%15.4f", 3467);
      3467.0000
|        |    |
1       10    5
```

In your browser you will not see the extra blanks, but if you additionally tell it to use a dot as the fill-character you will see it:

```
printf("%'.15.4f", 3467);
......3467.0000
|        |    |
1       10    5
```

As for your second question. You are formatting a signed value as unsigned output. -32 as unsigned 32 bit integer is FFFFFFE0. If you tell printf to output that as unsigned you will get the unsigned value of FFFFFFE0 which is 4294967264.

Comment: I did printf("%133.4f",3467); but no spaces (firebugged as well)  +1 for the second answer :)

Comment: Sorry, did not realize that you won't see adtional blanks there. Note that the output of printf("%1.6u", -32) depends on PHP_INT_SIZE in your case it seems to be 4.

Comment: it s all well and good ..you really possess very deep knowledge in PHP..must say :)